# Why is inline element behaves like this?

Tags: css, inline

while working on my project i found this strange(to me) behaviour of inline element if it starts new line. I will try to explain. Let's say we have some inline text in **p** tag - 150-250 symbols long. If a word wrapped with **span/a** tag that starts new line (starting from line 2 and so on) and has a **before** pseudo class applied with following styles:

```
&:before
    content: ''
    position: absolute
    top: 0
    left: 0
    width: 100%
    background: green
    height: 3px
```

, then width of that **span/a** element will become 100% of paragraph and height also grows. if that word has some text or even one letter before(that stars line instead) - everything is ok o_O.

I created a pen for that. You can see a **.wrap** element there to limit width so the **span** element is starting second line and you can see that behaviour.

https://codepen.io/antongrekov/pen/VweQqqp

It happens on latest Chrome/Opera, but ok on Firefox.
May be using before element with inline is wrong. I fixed this by using inline-block instead for element with before pseudo. If you change **max-width: 705.46px** value to some like 750 or any other you will move span element from its position and will see a green background applied to 100% width of span element, that is what code was intended for. But if span element stars line it doesn't work that way.

What do you think guys?

You may open developer console and select that span element with before pseudo to notice that it has some strange width and height.

Comment: At a guess, I'd say the `before` pseudo element literally appears before the `.red-box`, and is therefor on the previous line (And as none of the span is on that line, it will have 0 width and not be visible, but the container will expand to contain the "multi-line" span)

Comment: it's known that pseudo element with inline element is not a good idea and the rendring can be random and buggy due to the nature of the element

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I doubt it's quite that bad. Out-of-flow pseudo-elements sure. Any known problems with in-flow pseudo-elements?

Comment: @Alohci yes I was refering to only out-of-flow since the OP is using position:absolute but for the in-flow one there is no particular issue (unless you try to make a block element inside an inline element but this behavior is well defined in the Spec even if non-intuitive)